# How to add a custom UIView on top of the UITableViewCell runtime?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView having multiple custom cell. I want to add `custom View on top of the cell runtime`.

I have cell like this.

[image]

Now I want to add the `HR Channel top view` on the same cell runtime so that the it should look like this.

[image]
`As example :`

Think about facebook feed. It has a TableView with custom cells like Text Post Cell, Image Post Cell,Group Post Cell,Event cell, Page Post cell (Post which is posted in page).
 Now facebook add a custom view on top of the cell if someone has liked, comment or tagged on the post.

How can I add the custom view on top of the cell without creating one more custom cell?

Comment: You can use an UIStackView to hold the entire custom cell, including the HR channel part. You can set the HR channel part hide first, and set no hide in the code in the runtime. The UIStackView will automatic change the cell's view when the HR channel hide or show.

Comment: Hey @EricXuan Thanks. I did't know about the UIStackView ,I think this features came with iOS 9. Anyway you can write this as an answer. I will accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an UIStackView to hold the entire custom cell, including the HR channel part. And you can set the HR channel part hide first if needed, and set no hide in the code in the runtime. The UIStackView will automatic change the cell's view when the HR channel hide or show.

Holp it useful!

Answer (score 1):

Do one thing design your cell as per this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LZI8.png

Keep Icon, HR channel label and right icon on one view. Give height to it using constraints. Make IBOutlet of its height like

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *layoutConstraintHeightTopView;
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`check your condition whether to show it or not and change height constant as per that like

```
(isTopViewToShow == true) ? cell.layoutConstraintHeightTopView.constant = 50 : cell.layoutConstraintHeightTopView.constant = 0;
```

and also in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` check same condition and give heigh like

```
(isTopViewToShow == true) ? return 250 : return 200;
```

Hope this will help you !!!

Comment: this is a great option,even I thought about that . I think UIStackView will be a good use case for this. Thanks

Comment: If this is working solution the upvote my answer and accept it ;)

Comment: upvoted!! btw only one upvote is allowed. :) UIStackView is more appropriate answer I feel.